# PHP: CURL function using a form?

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I'm trying to convert UK postcodes to longs and lats using PHP.

so instead of using Google maps, I am going to use PHP CURL and use an alternative provider which is simpler to implement.

however, I have a problem making the CURL function to return anything using the input field in the form.

basically, I just need to put the Post Code in the input field in my form and press search and it should use the CURL and return the long and lat of that post code but my code doesn't do that and instead prints the input field value in the URL bar and that's it!

here is my entire code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
if (isset($_POST["postcode"])) {
function postCode2Geog($code){
//$code = strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$code));

$code = $_POST["postcode"];

 $uri = "http://www.streetmap.co.uk/streetmap.dll?GridConvert?name=".$code."&type=Postcode";

 $ch = curl_init($uri);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 preg_match('#long</strong> \(wgs84\)\s*?\<\/td\>\s*?\<td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle"\>\S{2,3}:\S{2}:\S{2} \( (.*?) \)#i',$output,$longMatch);
 preg_match('#lat</strong> \(wgs84\)\s*?\<\/td\>\s*?\<td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle"\>\S{2,3}:\S{2}:\S{2} \( (.*?) \)#i',$output,$latMatch);
 $long = $longMatch[1];
 $lat = $latMatch[1];

 return array($lat,$long);
}
}
?>
```

**and this is the HTML part:**

```
<form action="" method="GET">

<input type="text" name="postcode" />

<input type="submit" value="search" >
</form>
```

could someone please advise on this?

EDIT:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
if (isset($_POST["postcode"])) {

//$code = strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$code));

$code = $_POST["postcode"];

 $uri = "http://www.streetmap.co.uk/streetmap.dll?GridConvert?name=".$code."&type=Postcode";

 $ch = curl_init($uri);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 preg_match('#long</strong> \(wgs84\)\s*?\<\/td\>\s*?\<td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle"\>\S{2,3}:\S{2}:\S{2} \( (.*?) \)#i',$output,$longMatch);
 preg_match('#lat</strong> \(wgs84\)\s*?\<\/td\>\s*?\<td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle"\>\S{2,3}:\S{2}:\S{2} \( (.*?) \)#i',$output,$latMatch);
 $long = $longMatch[1];
 $lat = $latMatch[1];

 return array($lat,$long);
}
```

Comment: where are you actually calling that function? Your form method should also be `POST` since you're using `$_POST`

Comment: @ElefantPhace, i thought i was calling it inside the if(isset...) etc ?

Comment: no, you've just defined the function there. either define it elsewhere and call it from there, or do away with the function part and leave your curl methods where they are

Comment: @ElefantPhace, okay, I did what you said and I removed the function part and left the rest where they are but now I get Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on line 20 and Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on line 21....

Comment: well as no one here will magically know what's on those lines, look at my answer below.

Comment: @ElefantPhace, i've edited my answer mate... and those lines are  `preg_match('#long...` and  `preg_match('#lat...`

Comment: you need to do some checking on your `$output` and make sure you're actually getting a return.

Comment: look at my answer. I've posted a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, since you're wanting to use `$_POST` variables then you need to change your form method to `POST`

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

You're also never actually calling your function, but you would never know that because when you check `if(isset($_POST['whatever']))` it will never be set because you've been using `GET` as the form method.

You need to define your function outside of that code block, and call it from within.

Here is a working example: I've used a separate function to do the cURL to return any errors

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['postcode'])){
    $data = postCode2Geog($_POST['postcode']);
    var_dump($data);
}else{
    displayForm();
}

function displayForm(){
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='postcode' />";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='search' />";
    echo "</form>";
}

function postCode2Geog($code){
    $code = urlencode($code);
    $uri = "http://www.streetmap.co.uk/streetmap.dll?GridConvert?name=$code&type=Postcode";

    $output = url_get_contents($uri);

    preg_match('#long</strong> \(wgs84\)\s*?\<\/td\>\s*?\<td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle"\>\S{2,3}:\S{2}:\S{2} \( (.*?) \)#i',$output,$longMatch);
    preg_match('#lat</strong> \(wgs84\)\s*?\<\/td\>\s*?\<td width="50%" align="center" valign="middle"\>\S{2,3}:\S{2}:\S{2} \( (.*?) \)#i',$output,$latMatch);
    $long = $longMatch[1];
    $lat = $latMatch[1];

    return array('lat'=>$lat,'long'=>$long);
}

function url_get_contents($url){
    $crl = curl_init();
    $timeout = 10;
    curl_setopt_array($crl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'UTF-8',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => '1',
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => '1',
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $timeout)
    );
    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    $info = curl_getinfo($crl);

if ($ret === false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
   $ret = "No cURL data returned for $url [". $info['http_code']. "]";
   if (curl_error($crl))
     $ret .= "<br>\n Error: ". curl_error($crl) . "Code: " . curl_errno($crl);
}
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}
```

EC1R 4RR returns
`array(2) { ["lat"]=> string(9) "51.526254" ["long"]=> string(9) "-0.109119" }`

There edited so you can at least see which is which in the array. And to use them you would use `$data['lat']` and `$data['long']`

Comment: Thanks but all i needed was the actual $lat and $long but you seem to put everything in an array which makes it a bit difficult to extract the data from!

Comment: @william. that's the way that you had it, returned as an array. it's still not hard to get from the array though... But I went ahead and did more work for you. be happy.